# GridViewDataDateColumn - Trying to apply different date format in different row cells of the same column

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a GridViewDataDateColumn in ASPxGridView. I am trying to apply different date format in cells of the same column.

For example: I have a "CreatedDate" and "status" columns in an ASPxGridView and in each row I have to display the CreatedDate column value in "MM/dd/yyyy" format if the status is 1 and display the CreatedDate column value in "yyyy/MM/dd" format if the status is 2. So the date format will be different based on the status. The grid should look like this

Id    |  CreatedDate  |   Status
1001  |  05/22/2013   |   1
1002  |  2013/05/22   |   2
1003  |  07/15/2013   |   1
1004  |  2013/02/20   |   2

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to resolve it using `TemplateField`

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn HeaderText="Created Date">
<DataItemTemplate> 
  <asp:Label ID="CreatedDate" Runat="Server" 
      Text='<%# (int)Eval("Status") == 1 
          ? Eval("CreatedDate ", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") 
          : Eval("CreatedDate ", "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}") %>' />
</DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I am using "ASPxGridView" instead of "GridView".

Comment: I have added your code in <DataItemTemplate> and it worked. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @SanishThomas: np, updated my answer. Missed that you were talking about `ASPxGridView`. I don't have experience with it, hopefully I'm not making any mistake.